# How to read a text file with another application writing at the same time

Tags: c#

This is how I am reading a text file

```
string str;
 str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( @"C:\Text_1.txt");
```

if another application wants to write at the same time i am reading the file will it be able to get access of the same text file ?

Comment: I'd generally recommend against doing this. The application that wants to write to the file will probably be able to do it, but your application may not be able to access the file while writing is in progress

Comment: @Cerberton That is fine with my application not being able to acces while writing is in progress.

Comment: @Cerberton Also if you could please explain me how would you prefer this to be done ?

Comment: If you're targeting Windows, [Memory Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) might be a solution to your use case.

Comment: @Summit - to be honest I doubt my solution would be that useful - depending on the size of the file it may be impractical, but I would always create a copy of a file before subsequently reading it, to avoid any conflicts.